# How to write PHP SQL query in laravel terms

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4

How would I write this php mysql query in laravel's terms. I've checked the documentation and cannot find an IF or AS in there documentation for SQL in Laravel 4.2

This is the php query:

```
query("SELECT IF(friends.sender = ".$_SESSION["user"].", friends.recipient, friends.sender) AS user_id FROM friends WHERE friends.status=1 AND friends.sender = ".$_SESSION["user"]." OR friends.recipient = ".$_SESSION["user"]." AND friends.status=1 ")
```

I'm trying to format it like this,

```
@foreach(Friends::if("sender","=",Auth::user()->id)->as("user_id")->where("status","=",1)->where("sender","=",Auth::user()->id)->orWhere("recipient","=",Auth::user()->id)->where()->get() as $user_friends)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Query builder or Eloquent to do that

With Eloquent (this code will be added to the controller)

```
public function getFriends($arg1, $arg2)
{
  $friends = Frind::where('filed-name', 'operator', $arg1)->where('filed-name', 'operator', $arg2)->all();
  return view('/view-name', ['friends' => $friends];
}
```

or with Query Builder

```
public function getFriends($arg1, $arg2)
{
  $friends = DB::table('friends')->select('friends.*')->where('filed-name', 'operator', $arg1)->where('filed-name', 'operator', $arg2)->get();
  return view('/view-name', ['friends' => $friends];
}
```

You can read more on Query builder [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries) and Eloquent [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent).